# I cannot call my picture in xampp

Tags: html, wordpress, xampp

I'm trying to change html5 to wordpress theme. When I edit my coding and want to call picture its doesnt show it.

I setup wordpress in my Laptop using Xampp.

```
<img src="assets/img/user.png" alt="Stanley">
```

I think the code above is correct.

Or I need to make anychange so I can call my image?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What is your "current folder?"  `assets/img/user.png` probably ties into whatever folder is your current folder.

Comment: verify image permissions

Comment: Is the 'assets' folder in your theme directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your images into your theme folder at `wp-content/themes/theme-name` and use:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/user.png" alt="Stanley" />
```

This will ensure your image `src` uses an absolute path instead of a relative path.